# Mutate prevState in setState hooks updates the view without re-render. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My changeProductName function called setState which return a "mutated prevState". I pass the function to and call it in children component via ContextAPI. The function successfully updated a product name displayed in children and parent, but the parent did to fire a re-render. How does the parent updated the view without re-rendering? Can anyone explain what the prevState actually is in setState?

```
const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(initialValues);

  const changeProductName = (id, newName) => {
    setProducts((prevState) => {   //is preState a copy of state?  
      prevState.products.filter(
        (product) => product.id === id 
      )[0].name = newName;        //Mutates prevState
      return prevState;           //Did I return a new state?
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => 
    console.log("I would know when App re-renders")); //No re-render!

  return (
    <>    //Some React Switch and Routers 
    <div>
      {product.map(product=>product.name)}   //Successfully Updated!
    </div>
    <ProductContext value={(products, changeProductName)}> 
      <ProductPage />     //call changeProductName and it works!
    </ProductContext>
    </>   
  ); 
};
```

If I change the function not touching prevState, the parent re-renders as expected. Is this method better?

```
  //this will trigger parent re-render.
  const changeProductName = (id, newName) => { 
    setProducts((prevState) => {
      prevState.products.filter(
        (product) => product.id === id
      )[0].name = newName;
      return prevState;
    });
  };
```

Comment: You aren't using the retuen value of `prevState.filter(...)`. In order to mutate it, you need to use `filter` like this: `x = x.filter(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone explain what the prevState actually is in setState?

prevState is a reference to the previous state. It is not a copy of the state, it is a reference of the object that sits inside the state. So changing that object will not alter the object reference.

Therefore it should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from prevState.

For example, if you do a check inside your changeProduct name like:

```
setProducts(prevState => {
  prevState.filter(product => product.id == id)[0].name = newName;
  console.log(prevState === products); // This will console true
  return prevState;
});
```

Also, as you are using hooks, when you write `setProducts((prevState) => { prevState.products}`... the `prevState` itself is already the products. So you will get an undefined error in your example when trying to access `.products`.

So I would recommend you to do:

```
  const changeProductName = (id, newName) => {
    setProducts(prevProducts =>
      prevProducts.map(product =>
        product.id === id ? { ...product, name: newName } : product
      )
    );
  };
```

`.map` will build a new array based on prevState, and change the name of the products that have the id called in the function.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, mutating the state is generally a bad idea.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55178544/11817773), mutating the state may not result in a re-render, since the reference to the state object is not changed during the mutation.

I'd rather use some kind of redux-like immutable pattern:

```
const changeProductName = (id, newName) => { 
  setProducts((prevState) => (
    prevState.map(product=>{
      if(product.id!==id){
        // name is not changed since the id does not match
        return product;
      } else {
        // change it in the case of match
        return {...product, name:newName}
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: If you have a pure child component using a slice of parent's state which is an object. No matter if the object properties are the same, it would end up in a re-render. Because your set state is creating a new object reference each time. This re-render in its turn would be wasteful.